# Arduino Mega 2560 - stops code execution in while loop after successfully executing several times

Tags: c++, arduino, gps, freeze, i2c

I am currently working my way through a automated gps rover project using a arduino Mega 2560, a duinotech 3-way magnometer (5883L knock off) and duinotech gps reciever with onboard ariel. All components are working well on the arduino and executing in the main loop without issue.

```
...
void loop()
{
  bluetooth();
  delay(10); // Run the Bluetooth procedure to see if there is any data being sent via BT                                                    
  getGPS();  
  delay(10); // Update the GPS location
  getCompass();
  // Serial.println(compass_heading);
  delay(10);
  // Update the Compass Heading
}
...
```

However once I have some waypoints set and engage the automated driving function the program executes the loop 4 times then fails.

The function in question

```
...
void goWaypoint()
{   
    Serial.println(F("Go to Waypoint"));
    ac=ac-1;

    while (true)  
    {                                                                // Start of Go_Home procedure 
        // bluetooth();                                                     // Run the Bluetooth procedure to see if there is any data being sent via BT
        // if (blueToothVal == 4)
        //   {
        //   Serial.println("Bluetooth Break");
        //   break;
        //   }                                   // If a 'Stop' Bluetooth command is received then break from the Loop
        if (ac==-1){
            break;
        }
        Serial.println(F("Checking Compass"));
        getCompass();  
        delay(80);// Update Compass heading  
        Serial.println(F("Checking GPS"));                                        
        getGPS(); 
        delay(20);
        // Tiny GPS function that retrieves GPS data - update GPS location// delay time changed from 100 to 10
  
        if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10) 
        {               // If no Data from GPS within 5 seconds then send error
            Serial.println(F("No GPS data: check wiring"));     
        }
        Serial.println(F("Calculating"));
        Distance_To_Home = TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(gps.location.lat(),gps.location .lng(),Home_LATarray[ac], Home_LONarray[ac]);  //Query Tiny GPS for Distance to Destination
        GPS_Course = TinyGPSPlus::courseTo(gps.location.lat(),gps.location.lng(),Home_LATarray[ac],Home_LONarray[ac]);                               //Query Tiny GPS for Course to Destination   
        Serial.println(F("The Distance to waypoint: "));
        Serial.println(Distance_To_Home);
        Serial.println(F("The GPS Course Needed: "));
        Serial.println(GPS_Course);
    
        if (Distance_To_Home <= 1.5)                                   // If the Vehicle has reached it's Destination, then Stop
        {
            StopCar();                                               // Stop the robot after each waypoint is reached
            Serial.println(F("You have arrived!"));                    // Print to Bluetooth device - "You have arrived"          
            ac--;                                                    // increment counter for next waypoint
            if (ac==-1) {
                break;
            }                                                   // Break from Go_Home procedure and send control back to the Void Loop                                                                  // go to next waypoin      
        }   
        else if ( abs(GPS_Course - compass_heading) <= 30)                  // If GPS Course and the Compass Heading are within x degrees of each other then go Forward                                                                                                                                    
        {                                                          // otherwise find the shortest turn radius and turn left or right
           Forward();                                               // Go Forward
        }
        else 
        {                                                       
            int x = (GPS_Course - 360);                           // x = the GPS desired heading - 360
            int y = (compass_heading - (x));                      // y = the Compass heading - x
            int z = (y - 360);                                    // z = y - 360
            
            if ((z <= 180) && (z >= 0))                           // if z is less than 180 and not a negative value then turn left otherwise turn right
            { 
                 Serial.println(F("Turning Left:"));
                 SlowLeftTurn();
            }
            else 
            { 
                Serial.println(F("Turning Right"));
                SlowRightTurn(); 
            }               
        } 
    }                                                              // End of While Loop 
}                                                                // End of Go_Home procedure
...
```

And finally the two functions connecting to the instrumentation

```
void getGPS()                                                 // Get Latest GPS coordinates
{
    while (Serial2.available() > 0)
    gps.encode(Serial2.read());
    delay(60);
} 

void getCompass()                                               // get latest compass value
{  

    Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

    float declinationAngle = (21.5 + (26.0 / 60.0)) / (180 / M_PI);

    // Calculate heading
    float heading = atan2(norm.YAxis, norm.XAxis);
    heading += declinationAngle;
    // heading = heading-0.4;
 
    if(heading < 0)
        heading += 2 * M_PI;      
    compass_heading = (int)(heading * 180/M_PI);  
    delay(100);                 // assign compass calculation to variable (compass_heading) and convert to integer to remove decimal places                                                              

}
```

The code as mentioned starts to operate then fails,just freezing, on the fourth time through (much of the delays and outputs are added in my attempts to debug) right after the getCompass() call. I suspect a memory leak maybe???? Any Advice/Help would be appreciated.

Picture of freeze
[code halted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fkrd.png)

EDIT: Added some more prints into getCompass()
...

```
void getCompass()                                               // get latest compass value
{  
    Serial.println(F("In getCompass"));
    Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

    float declinationAngle = 0.418;

    // Calculate heading
    Serial.println(F("Before Atan"));
    float heading = atan2(norm.YAxis, norm.XAxis);
    heading += declinationAngle;
    // heading = heading-0.4;
    Serial.println(F("Positive Balance"));
    if(heading < 0)
        heading += 2 * M_PI;  
    Serial.println(F("Radians to degrees"));    
    compass_heading = (int)(heading * 180/M_PI);  
    delay(100);                 // assign compass calculation to variable (compass_heading) and convert to integer to remove decimal places                                                              
    Serial.println(F("Get Compass Finished"));
}
```

...
with the result that the call freezes after the "In compass" print so the issue maybe be compass.normalise function.

I am a beginner with arduino and low level coding so am unsure at how to proceed now, why does this work fine when called in the main loop but is siezing the code in this while loop?

Updated execution screen
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUM4p.png)

Compass Library I am using https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-HMC5883L

Edit 2: Messing around in getCompass() further I managed to get the code working by commenting out.

```
float declinationAngle = 0.418;
heading += declinationAngle;
```

I am now completely lost, why was this causing the code to freeze and what is the best way around it to remove the declination angle to calculate direction without using a float.

EDIT 3: Added to include compass setup.

```
void setup() 
{  
  
  Serial.begin(115200);                                            // Serial 0 is for communication with the computer and magnometer.
  Serial.println("In Setup");
  // Serial1.begin(11520);                                             // Serial 1 is for Bluetooth communication - DO NOT MODIFY - JY-MCU HC-010 v1.40
  Serial2.begin(9600);                                             // Serial 2 is for GPS communication at 9600 baud - DO NOT MODIFY - Ublox Neo 6m  
  // Motors
  pinMode(leftMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightMotor, OUTPUT);
  // bluetooth buffer
  indx = 0;
  // Compass
  Serial.println("Compass setup");
  while (!compass.begin()) 
  {                       
    Wire.begin();                             // Join I2C bus used for the HMC5883L compass
    Serial.println("Bus OK");
    compass.begin();                                                 // initialize the compass (HMC5883L)
    Serial.println("Compass Object Created");
    compass.setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);                          // Set measurement range  
    compass.setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);                  // Set measurement mode  
    compass.setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_15HZ);                     // Set data rate  
    compass.setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8);                          // Set number of samp5les averaged  
    compass.setOffset(65,-290);                                          // Set calibration offset
    Serial.println("Calibrated Compass");
  }
  Serial.println("Setup Complete");
  Startup();                                                       // Run the Startup procedure on power-up one time
}
```

And the startup() function as part of the setup:

```
void Startup()
{
      
     for (int i=5; i >= 1; i--)                       // Count down for X seconds
      {         
        Serial.print("Pause for Startup... "); 
        Serial.print(i);
        delay(1000);                                   // Delay for X seconds
      }    
  Serial.println("Searching for Satellites ");     
  while (Number_of_SATS < 4)                         // Wait until x number of satellites are acquired before starting main loop
  {              
    Serial.println("Small delay for home co-ordinates to be recieved");
    delay(10);                    
    getGPS();                                         // Update gps data
    Serial.print("Number of Sats: ");
    Serial.println(int(gps.satellites.value()));
    Number_of_SATS = (int)(gps.satellites.value());   // Query Tiny GPS for the number of Satellites Acquired       
    bluetooth();                                      // Check to see if there are any bluetooth commands being received  
    Serial.println("Looping for SATS"); 
  }                                        // set intial waypoint to current location
  wpCount = 0;                                        // zero waypoint counter
  ac = 0;                                             // zero array counter 
  Serial.print(Number_of_SATS);
  Serial.print(" Satellites Acquired");
  Serial.println(" Start-up Complete");   
}
```

Comment: In `getCompass()` you call `readNormalize()` and `atan2()`, two probable culprits.  Have you added more prints to see where execution stops?

Comment: Done. Updated with an edit in the original question at the end. It seems to be readNormalize() do you have any suggestions why it is causing this and the best way to approach resolving it?

Comment: Added further discoveries to original question

Comment: The `readNormalize()` function you are using calls `readRegister16()` to read a few HMC5883L registers over i2c.  The library function `readRegister16()` does a blocking wait for an i2c reply: `while(!Wire.available()) {};` so if the magnetometer doesn't reply, you will be stuck forever.  Does your setup have sufficient power?  A motorized,  moving setup will have quite uneven current consumption, so the current peaks may coincide with voltage dropouts (and perhaps low battery). Are all wires connected firmly?

Comment: Power is stable, but yes wiring is.... was a tad dodgy mainly due to me learning to solder on this project. However the lines pass a connection test with a multimeter. In messing around with it further yesterday I found the freeze could be removed by taking out the float decleration in the getCompass() function and delcaring it as a constant float with the rest of the variable declerations. I have no idea why or how this worked in removing the freeze however.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to resolve the issue by taking the float declaration out of the getCompass() function and declare it as a global const float. Why this was causing the error and why the error would occur when being run as part of the goWaypoint() function I have no idea, so please feel free to add to this question if anybody knows the reasoning. I am leaving this answer here in the meantime in case any other users run across a similar issue.

UPDATE: This continues to unresolved in the space of 24hrs with no changes to the code the uav went back to the same situation where the code is siezing in the getCompass() function the only difference is that now it is seizing at the vector norm = compass.normalize() line. I tried making all the variables in the function global rather than local, this however had no effect. I am starting to wonder if this may be a hardware issue with the main board.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/what-is-the-default-stack-size-for-function-calls/81357/10) for ways to measure free RAM, since you are suspecting *stack overflow.* The code you've posted isn't complete, so I can't see how much RAM is being used for other things

Comment: Thank you, that link is most helpful. The full program takes 6% of program memory space, 16% of dynamic memory with variables when uploaded. Moving the local variable to global has fixed the issue, as I have now had time to run some lengthy tests, so I'm guessing some memory allocation shenanigans must of happened with it being declared locally.

Comment: To me this sounds like stack corruption, not a memory leak.  How have you declared the Vector datatype, and defined+initialized compass? What's in your `setup()`?

Comment: Made some edits in main post to show the setup which contains the compass initialization. The vector comes from the compass library I was using https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-HMC5883L which I believe in turn uses it from the hmc588L library. It has every chance of not being a memory leak, that was more of an uneducated stab in the dark from me.

Comment: Testing of the vehicle today met with a return of failure, see edit above.